# Tick labels are chopped in PolarPlot output

Tags: plotting

When I enter the following code:

`PolarPlot[1, {t, -Pi, Pi}, PolarAxes -> {True, False},  PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic},  PolarGridLines -> {True, False}]`

Mathematica generates the following output:

[image: output]

It is obvious that some labels for `PolarTicks` are outside plot range and therefore not fully visible. I managed to solve the problem partially by using the `ImageSize->` option; however, doing so makes the image unacceptably large (as it occupies the entire screen). Any solutions/workarounds would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a bug to me. Nonetheless, you can add padding to it:

```
PolarPlot[1, {t, -Pi, Pi}, PolarAxes -> {True, False}, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
 PolarGridLines -> {True, False}, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The issue is caused by the default option value for [`PlotRangeClipping`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangeClipping.html):

```
Options[PolarPlot, PlotRangeClipping]
```

> ```
> {PlotRangeClipping -> True}
> ```

Use `PlotRangeClipping -> False` to prevent clipping of labels:

```
PolarPlot[1, {t, -Pi, Pi}, PolarAxes -> {True, False}, 
  PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, 
  PolarGridLines -> {True, False}, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False]
```

[image]